# assigning words from a list to a string with spaces between each word

Tags: python, string, list, loops

I want to transfer words from a list to an empty string, but i also need the words to be separated by space.e.g not sticking together.

for example:

```
def list_to_string(words):
    sentence = ""
    for word in words:
        sentence = sentence + word
return sentence
```

Testing:

```
list_to_string(["moo", "lee", "raa", "soo"])
'mooleeraasoo'
```

But what im looking for is a space character between each two words:

```
'moo lee raa soo'
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use `str.join`:  `' '.join(["moo", "lee", "raa", "soo"])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each iteration, add a space along with the word and finally do stripping when returning the resultant string.

```
def list_to_string(words):
    sentence = ""
    for word in words:
        sentence += word + " "
    return sentence.rstrip()     # before returning the string, this would strip all the trailing spaces.
```

Comment: I understand what line (4) does, but would u be able to explain what " .strip() " in line (5) does? thanks

Comment: `string.rstrip()` function will remove all the trailing spaces present in the string.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a single line `join` without using loops.

```
' '.join(["moo", "lee", "raa", "soo"])
'moo lee raa soo'
```